# How to mock lifecycleScope for Unit Test?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-lifecycle

I`m writing unit tests for my lifecycleScope, but having trouble executing the tests.

Can someone tell me how to mock lifecycleScope appropriately?

sample code:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {
  fun test() {
      lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           val a = test2()
      }

  }

  suspend fun test2(): Boolean = true

}
```

Can someone tell me how to mock lifecycleScope appropriately?
Thanks!!!